# Sometimes on click executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a very strange problem. Basically I have created a menu in wordpress that has parent, childs, subchilds and inside some posts.

I wrote a jquery script that adds a highlight class on the `<li>` in order to expand the `<ul>` which is inside the `<li>`. the format of the list is the following

```
<li class"menu-item-has-children"><a>Parent</a>
<ul>
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a>Child</a>
<ul>
<li class="menu-item-has-children"><a>Sub Child</a>
<ul>
<li><a> post</a></li>
<li><a> post 2 </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

So I wrote the following script to add highlight class to expand the sub child of the clicked `<li>`. When I'm clicking on any `<li>` of parent,child, sub child is working fine but when I click on the posts it removes the highlight class from the parent `<ul>` instead of taking me to the page of the clicked post.

I did a console log of $(this) and when click on any parent, child,sub child it shows me `<ul>` that has, but when I click on any posts it shows me first the `<a>` tag that it has followed by the parent `<ul>`. Does anyone know why?

Here is my jquery code

```
  $(document).unbind("click").on('click',".sidebar-right li",function(e){
    var found = false;
    var tmp = String($(this).val());
    if (tmp.indexOf("ul") != -1){
      found = true;
    }
    if (($(this).hasClass("menu-item-has-children")) && (!$(this).children('ul').hasClass("highlight")))
    {
      $(this).children("a").addClass("highlight_icon");
      $(this).children('ul').addClass("highlight");
      return false;
    }
    else if (($(this).has("a") && ($(this).has("ul"))) && (!$(this).children('ul').hasClass("highlight")))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else if ($(this).children('ul').hasClass("highlight"))
    {
      $(this).children('a').removeClass("highlight_icon");
      $(this).children('ul').removeClass("highlight");
      return false;
    }
    else 
    {
      return true;
    }

  });
```

Here is the console log data
Child Parent etc
[image]

Post click
[image]

SOLUTION: event.stopPropagation() as @mohamed-yousef said

Comment: if I got your point .. try use  [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(".sidebar-right").on('click',".sidebar-right li", function(){

  ....});
```